# Promise version of minimum distance

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, coding-theory, np

It has been known for some time that computing minimum distance of a linear code (minimum weight codeword) is NP-hard.
This immediately also says that given a code $C$, calculating minimum hamming distance  of its dual is also hard.
What I am particularly interested in is some combination of these two.

For example, is the following NP-complete:

Given a matrix $G=[I|A]$ let $C_G$ denote code generated by $G$. Does at least one of $C_G$ or $C_G^{\perp}$ (dual code) contain a codeword of weight less than or equal to $t$.

On the similar lines one can also look at promise version of minimum distance,

Promise: C is self dual ($C^\perp= C$). Compute minimum distance of $C$.

Is anything known about hardness of these?